# How to get the indexpath or particular id from single list view cell on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have list of items that i am displaying from db. So in each cell i have one button . So each cell have one seperate number ID .So when ever i press any cell button.That particular cell number id i need to get .Just to put one alert or console message to get that particular number ID. How to do that.

For example :

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="colls in Mycolls | filter: search | limitTo: listlength">
   <div>
      <img src="img/Reminder.png"> 
      <span>Get number</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="img/phone.png">
      <span>GET NAME</span>
   </div>
</ion-item>
```

This above code is my list view to populate my data, with each cell have one button.Please help me out how can i do that using `ng-click`.

Here my controller:

```
.controller('collectionsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $window, $ionicPopup, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $ionicHistory, collectionsfactory) {
    $scope.GoBack = function() {
        $state.go('menu.mydata');
    };
    $scope.mdID = "1";
    $scope.orderInfo = {
        mdID: $scope.mdID
    };
    $ionicLoading.show();
    collectionsfactory.save($scope.orderInfo, function(response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $scope.Mycolls = response.allcollections;
            $window.localStorage.setItem("order", JSON.stringify($scope.Mycolls));
            console.log($scope.Mycolls);
        } else {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: "Failed",
                content: "<center>" + response.message + "</center>"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ng-click` to the `span` in the repeated element that call your functions:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="colls in Mycolls" ng-click="getColls(colls)>
    <span ng-click="getNumber(colls)">Get number</span>
    <span ng-click="getName(colls)">Get name</span>
</ion-item>
```

Here are `getNumber()` and `getName()` functions in controller:

```
$scope.savedColls = {};

$scope.getNumber = function(colls) {
    $scope.savedColls.number = colls.number;
}

$scope.getName = function(colls) {
    $scope.savedColls.name = colls.name;
}
```

Comment: @Mistails  Sorry for update. I have two button called `Get Number`, `Get name`. So how can i differentiate a click only for `Get number` button alone. to get my particular cell number ID.

Comment: yes worked.In your solution i got all the data about that particular cell. And i seperate it by using ` console.log("Colls getted!", colls.NumberID);` So that i got my number id. But can i save this number ID ....To use this number in future ?? How can i save it in some variable ??

Comment: Yes how can i save that number, is some varibale . So that i can  use that particular varibale in some where in future

Comment: @sinha Just declare a variable `$scope.savedColls = {}` and set its properties on the function. I've updated my answer, please accept it if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

call a function by ng-click and pass the id

In html

```
<span ng-click="getName(colls.name)"></span>
<span ng-click="getNumber(colls.number)"></span>
```

Inside the controller

```
$scope.getName = function(name) {
console.log('cell name',name);
}
$scope.getNumber = function(number) {
console.log('cell number',number);
}
```

Comment: I am getting in console like `undefined`. Sorry for update. I have two button called `Get Number`, `Get name`. So how can i differentiate a click only for `Get number` button alone. to get my particular cell number ID.

Comment: please try the updated one. here you can call two different functions from diffrent button. hope this will help you.